# Switch values in MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have a table in MySQL with a field "Ordering" These are just auto incremented numbers. Now I wonder if there is a query to change the values from the last to the first...
So the entry with ordering 205 should become 1, 204 -> 2 and so on...

It's actually not an auto-increment. The problem is I started adding projects from the current website. From page 1 to page 20, but the first item on page 1 is the latest. The way I added the new projects, the newest is on the last page..

If the ordering field is switched, the new items added will be correctly numbered again and added to the front page. It's just a wrong way I started adding old projects...

[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1k60W.jpg)

[Examples of the content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvNDw.jpg)

Comment: Changing auto-incremented values are a real bad idea, why not just use `order by` for display purpose ?

Comment: Add more details here, example data and an example result.

Comment: More details added :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment due to limitations, but i really agree with @Abhik Chakraborty.
You don't want to do this. Just use the order by as he suggested.
Example:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName
ORDER BY columnName DESC;
```

Just in case you would like to know more about it: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this as one statement call:

```
    SET @MaxSort := (SELECT MAX(Ordering) FROM MyTable);
    UPDATE MyTable t set t.Ordering = (@MaxSort + 1 - t.Ordering);
```

This will work if field doesn't have unique constraint.
But this field, should not be an auto_increment field at first place. Auto increment is increasing NOT decreasing counter. Except if you just try to fix existing data and the new records will be increasing.

**Additional explanation**

Thanks for pointing it out. Multiple query inside single query statement doesn't work with php_mysqli and it is not used because of potential MySQL injection attack if servers allows it. Maybe you can setup PHPMyAdmin to use PHP PDO.

I can use multiple queries, but I'm using PHP PDO or DBeaver database manager.

I can only suggest to supply MaxSort manually (since this is one time job anyway):

```
UPDATE
    MyTable t
set
    t.Ordering = 254 - t.Ordering + 1;
```

Comment: I now added screenshots of the table and structure

Comment: Tried this SQL query, but didn't seem to work... SET @MaxSort := (SELECT MAX(ordering) FROM aaa_advportfoliopro_projects);
    UPDATE aaa_advportfoliopro_projects t set t.ordering = (@MaxSort + 1 - t.ordering);